# How to capture and store network packets using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am sorry if the question seems vague. However, I am interested in this project which I found in the link below

http://1000projects.org/network-intrusion-detection-system.html#comment-249119.

If I am correct, I think this application captures and stores the network packets into a SQL Server database. But I am not sure, if I can capture it using C#

I would love an explanation because this is an awesome project and I know it would be a good challenge for me

Thanks All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would want is to mimic [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark)'s capability to capture packets from the physical network device. This requires some heavy lifting already done for you by the WinPcap kit.

You may want to look at .NET ports for WinPcap, such as [PcapDotNet](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net) or [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/).

Both frameworks allow you to capture raw packets and send raw packets.

Comment: Can I use .NET API to capture raw packets?

Comment: Please refer to the libraries that I've linked.